# iMacros / Select random photo from PC

Tags: imacros

I need to make iMacros to automatically choose random photo from a folder on my PC. How do I arrange it?
This is the line from iMacros for adding some file manually:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-insta-image-upload CONTENT=/path/to/the/specific/file
```

Thanks.

**For *Shugar***

Here’s how my script looks like:

asd.iim

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://onlypult.com/dashboard
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Calendar
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:+
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-insta-image-upload CONTENT={{rndFilePath}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-nextsubmit--2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-nextsubmit--3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-saveimaage
```

asd.js

```
SET folderPath /path/to/folder/
SET rndFilePath EVAL("var arrFile = []; var file = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); file.initWithPath('{{folderPath}}'); var filesEnum = file.directoryEntries; while (filesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {arrFile.push(filesEnum.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile).path);} arrFile[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arrFile.length))];")
PROMPT {{rndFilePath}}
```

Both files are in folder /iMacros/Macros.
When it comes to line with CONTENT={{rndFilePath}}, nothing happens.
Normally that line looks like this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:insta-add-image-form-all ATTR=ID:edit-insta-image-upload CONTENT=/path/to/content.jpg
```

The thing is, I need to click and choose some file because there appears dropdown menu when I click on «upload from PC», I cannot just write copy-paste the path to the file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If  you’re using Firefox, the code below returns the full path to a random file from the folder ‘D:\Temp\img’ (specified with the ‘folderPath’ variable).

```
SET folderPath D:\\\Temp\\\img
SET rndFilePath EVAL("var arrFile = []; var file = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); file.initWithPath('{{folderPath}}'); var filesEnum = file.directoryEntries; while (filesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {arrFile.push(filesEnum.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile).path);} arrFile[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arrFile.length))];")
PROMPT {{rndFilePath}}
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn’t work. I’m writing all info in another answer.

Comment: My code is NOT ‘.js’ - it’s a simple ‘.iim’! Run my macro separately and check how it’s working. If it solves the part of your task (i.e. it “selects random photo from PC”), you can go ahead and join both codes after having made all necessary changes.

Comment: When I click on «upload» I am unable to do anything because I’m having this kind of window and I just cannot click on anything. [screen shot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2djctio.jpg)

Comment: Once again! Play my macro SEPARATELY and check whether it “automatically chooses a random photo from the folder on your PC”... And leave the file picker for the next step.

Comment: I’m so sorry, but I don’t really understand what do you mean. When I play your script without anything else in it, I get an error `ReferenceError: Components is not defined, line 2 (Error code: -1001)`.

Comment: My configuration is: Firefox 35.0.1 and iMacros 8.8.8. At least in such conditions the iim-code works as needed.

Comment: Installed the same versions of both Firefox and iMacros, still getting that error. Maybe I’m doing something wrong. You mean I should just play in no matter on what page I am? If so, then I have no idea what’s wrong. By the way, I’m using mac, maybe that’s could be a problem?

Comment: Yes, no matter on what page you are… Maybe mac indeed creates the problem. Nevertheless, in order to eliminate subjective factors you may contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and I’ll give you similar js-script as a last variant I can suggest.