# SET !ERRORIGNORE NO does not work in firefox but works in Imacros browser

Tags: firefox, imacros

The Task is simple. If picture is found upload it and complete the loop, otherwise stop. Here is the code.

```js
VERSION BUILD=10.4.28.1074
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Mir\Desktop\twan1\input3.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 27
SET !LOOP 464
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=mywebsite    // website url
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Myhome 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Artikel<SP>anlegen

SET !ERRORIGNORE NO  // The error check code
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:image1 CONTENT=C:\Users\Mir\Pictures\twan_auto\{{!COL13}} // the picture in question

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_VPEinheit CONTENT={{!COL16}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_minbestellmenge CONTENT={{!COL17}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_nettopreis CONTENT={{!COL18}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_spm1 CONTENT={{!COL19}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_spp1 CONTENT={{!COL20}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=TXT:Weitere<SP>Staffelpreise<SP>anlegen
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_spm2 CONTENT={{!COL21}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_spp2 CONTENT={{!COL22}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_verMenge CONTENT={{!COL23}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:ff_mwst CONTENT={{!COL24}}
```

This code works fine is imacros browser. If there is no picture, the imacros browser shows correctly the following error: Error -1230: Cannot find file C:\Users\Mir\Desktop\twan_auto\picture.jpg. Please make sure to specify full path, or a path relative to iMacros Downloads directory. Line 22: TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE
But this does not work in firefox browser. When I run it in firefox it completes the loop, even if there is no picture. Thx in advance :)

Comment: Firefox really doesn’t throw an error if the specified file hasn’t been found on your PC. The only way I can suggest is to use js-script instead of your iim-macro and take the idea of file system access as proposed in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491562/imacros-select-random-photo-from-pc. (And 'SET !ERRORIGNORE NO' is set by default and doesn't concern this issue currently.)

Comment: firefox still does not throw any error. 'var macro;
macro = "CODE:"; 
macro += "VERSION BUILD=8031994" + "\n";
macro += "TAB T=1     " + "\n";
macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS  " + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE input3.csv" + "\n";
macro += "SET !LOOP 464" + "\n";
macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=mywebsite" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ID:prodMGMT ATTR=NAME:image1 CONTENT=C:\\Users\\Mir\\Desktop\\twan_auto\\{{!COL13}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro);
iimGetLastError();
alert(iimGetLastExtract());'

Comment: I used this command _macro += "SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE C:\\Users\\Mir\\Desktop\\twan_auto\\{{!COL14}}" + "\n";_ to access the file and it seems to be working (firefox now shows an error).

Comment: Have you read the post I told about?.. Is there an issue in the ‘SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE’ command but not in the ‘CONTENT’ attribute?..

Comment: yes I read the post. The command _SET folderPath /path/to/folder/_ was not working for me. So I used the command _SET !FOLDER_DATASOURCE_  and it is working as expected. i.e. If picture is found upload it and complete the loop, otherwise stop. Thanks for the Idea :)